# Get rows that differ

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `properties`:

```
propertyID  userID  defaultStateID  defaultStateYear
1           1       1               2017
2           1       2               2017
3           2       1               2018
4           3       3               2018
```

Each property belongs to certain user (user 1 has properties 1, 2; user 2 has property 3, user 3 has property 4). Each property has a default state identified by defaultStateID and defaultStateYear (referring to table `states` below).

Then I have a table `states` showing data about properties at certain points of time (data about them - owner and area - change from time to time):

```
stateID propertyID  owner          area timestamp    stateYear
1       1           David Smith    15   123456789    2017
2       2           Amanda Green   74   123456799    2017
3       1           David Smith    15   123456999    2017
1       3           Amanda Green   12   123459999    2018
2       1           Peter Black    11   123499999    2018
3       4           Jack Stone     62   123999999    2018
4       2           Amanda Green   70   129999999    2018
```

Combination of stateID and stateYear is unique in this table.

In the example above, state of propertyID 1 changed from its default state (stateID 1 in year 2017) compared with the most recent state (stateID 2 in year 2018). Similarly, state of propertyID 2 changed.

How to show changes for certain user in his properties (using MySQL)?

Desired output (for userID 1):

```
propertyID  owner         area  timestamp
1           David Smith   15    123456789
1           Peter Black   11    123499999
2           Amanda Green  74    123456799
2           Amanda Green  70    129999999
```

I tried the following piece of code but the code is just loading for unlimited time (in phpMyAdmin) giving no output/error:

```
SELECT p.propertyID,    -- getting default state of property
   p.defaultStateID,
   p.defaultStateYear,
   s.owner AS owner,
   s.area AS area,
   s.timestamp AS timestamp
FROM properties AS p
LEFT JOIN states AS s
ON p.propertyID = s.propertyID
AND p.defaultStateID =
  (SELECT si.stateID
   FROM states AS si
   WHERE si.stateID = p.defaultStateID AND si.stateYear = p.defaultStateYear AND p.userID=1)
UNION ALL
SELECT p.propertyID,    -- getting the most recent state of property
   p.defaultStateID,
   p.defaultStateYear,
   s.owner AS owner,
   s.area AS area,
   s.timestamp AS timestamp
FROM properties AS p
LEFT JOIN states_full AS s
ON p.property_id = s.property_id
AND s.timestamp = 
   (SELECT MAX(timestamp)
   FROM states
   WHERE s.propertyID = p.propertyID)
WHERE p.userID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly this query here should do the trick for you :

```
SELECT s.propertyID, s.owner, s.area, s.timestamp
FROM states s
INNER JOIN properties p ON p.propertyID = s.propertyID
WHERE p.defaultStateID = s.stateID
AND p.userID = 1
```

- First, we're selecting out columns that we need.
- Second, we're doing an "INNER JOIN" so we can get only the data that
  match our property.
- After that we're filtering for the default state to be equal to the
  stateID, and because you specified the desired output for user 1, I
  have added a filter for userID matching the first user.

  Hope that this is helpful for you.

Comment: Boian, thanks for giving explanation. It seems that it gives only default states of user's properties - as you can see in the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd155/2/0 . What I am looking for is couple of states (default + last) for each property whose states changed between default and last state.

Comment: Sorry John, that my answer wasn't of any help to you. As I've seen though, the answer that Gordon has provided does the thing that you need so at least you found help here. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the initial and last states for a given user's properties.

However, your data model is *very* confusing.  Why would something called `stateid` be duplicated in a table called `states`?  Why would the join between the tables be on property and year?  These really don't make sense.  The database is not making proper use of keys on tables.

But, based on your description, this would seem to do what you want:

```
select s.*
from properties p join
     (select s2.propertyid, max(s2.year) as maxyear
      from states s2
      group by s2.propertyid
     ) sp
     on sp.propertyid = p.propertyid join
     states s
     on s.propertyid = p.propertyid and
        s.year in (p.year, sp.maxyear)
order by sp.propertyid, sp.year;
```

EDIT:

This appears to do what you want:

```
select s.*
from properties p join
     (select s2.propertyID, max(s2.timestamp) as maxtimestamp
      from states s2
      group by s2.propertyID
     ) sp
     on sp.propertyID = p.propertyID join
     states s
     on s.propertyID = p.propertyID and
        (s.timestamp = sp.maxtimestamp or
         s.stateId = p.defaultStateID
        )
where p.userID = 1
order by sp.propertyID;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd155/4) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: As regards data model, I agree, however - it is a result of historic development and I am not able to change it (actually table states is a VIEW of many individual tables state_year - e.g. state_2018, state_2017, etc.). I tried your code but it seems it returns all states of all properties - you can check in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd155/1/0 (where I edited a bit your code to output user_id 1 properties only as this is sought). Only properties which states changed should be given in the result and from those properties only default + last state.

Comment: Thanks, we are getting close. The last thing is whether we can list only properties where some change in states occurred? So to skip those where no change happened.

Comment: @JohnPeeterson . . . You can add `having count(*) > 1` to the first subquery.

Comment: Actually by change in states it is meant a change in any of values "owner" or "area" between states. The couple of states should be returned only when any of these values changed (between default and the last state).